# Selenium interaction with Address Picker

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I have an address picker widget on my page (details below) that accepts a partial address and then displays a list of suggested addresses to be selected. This works fine manually, and a list of suggestions is displayed. However, when I use Selenium to sendKeys (and I have also tried JS Exec to do the same), the string is entered but no suggestions are made. It looks like the JS to fetch the suggestions is not being triggered. Any ideas how to activate it?

```
<input type="text" name="nodeW327-Address1" id="nodeW327-Address1" aria-
autocomplete="list" aria-describedby="W327Hint" aria-required="true" 
class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

Here's what it should look like, but the list does not appear:

[image]

Comment: Check your HTML source/JS to find, which event triggers the list.

Comment: Your code trials and the relevant _HTML_ please.